# How do I remove file extension from $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Tags: php, file-extension

I am using a script that populates a page with a hyperlink made up of the current URL. So, for instance, if the visitor goes to mysite.com/thispage.php then it will automatically create a link for them on their own page. Then, they can simply click that link to return the page at any time.

To create this link I am using a variable $link which grabs the current pages URL, like this:

```
$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

The only issue I am having is that I have the php extension removed from the URLs on the site so the visitor doesn't have to type them (yes, I know, reasons, blah... I have a specific need for this) However, when the $link is created the .php extension is added.

Is there another way to write this so it doesn't grab the extension, or something to add to the string to remove it?

Comment: Just use the _correct_ value to begin with … You don’t want PHP_SELF, you want REQUEST_URI.

Comment: @CBroe why? The URI requesting access changes, and it returns the file extension either way. Doesn't seem to help anything.

Comment: REQUEST_URI is the actual URL requested by the client, so that should not contain the file suffix to begin with in this case. (If it does, then you have likely rather set up your removal of the extension wrong somehow.) PHP_SELF is always the name of the main script file that is getting executed, so that will always include the suffix.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will look into my extension removal, but I think what I was seeing was in the echo I did. I'll go hide now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look

```
pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

The [second argument to pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) strips the extension from the file name (PHP >= 5.2)

hope this helps!

Comment: It also stripped the backslash prior to. I had to add it back in , but it works now. `$link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/" . pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);`